# Is it possible to manually configure between ARMv7 and Thumb instruction set when compiling for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, arm, windows-phone

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app, and testing it on Lumia 920 (having Snapdragon S4 processor, supporting ARMv7 instruction set).
My project includes native code which is written in C++ language.

I would like to understand how the compiler makes the decision to switch between ARMv7 instruction set, and THUMB instruction set for a given piece of code.

And is it possible to manually configure Visual Studio to use only ARMv7 or THUMB instruction set for building the machine code?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 officially supports only ARMv7 Thumb2 and Microsoft's compiler does not produce ARM code when compiling for it. If you use another compiler it should be possible to compile some parts in ARM mode but there might be issues when running it (e.g. I'm not sure if exceptions can be correctly propagated through ARM mode functions).